# Approximate $f''(x)$ given $f(x),f(x+h),f(x+3h),f(x-5h)$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

> Given $f(x),f(x+h),f(x+3h),f(x-5h)$, approximate $f''(x)$.

Book's solution: From Taylor' series,
$$ 
\\ f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+0.5f''(x)h^2+{1\over6}f'''(x)h^3+O(h^4)
\\ f(x+3h)=f(x)+3f'(x)h+4.5f''(x)h^2+4.5f'''(x)h^3+O(h^4)
\\ f(x-5h)=f(x)-5f'(x)h+12.5f''(x)h^2-{125\over6}f'''(x)h^3+O(h^4)
$$
Thus,
$$
\\ af(x+h)+bf(x+3h)+cf(x-5h)+df(x)=
\\(a+b+c+d)f(x)+(a+3b-5c)f'(x)h+(0.5a+4.5b+12.5c)f''(x)h^2+({a\over6}+{27\over6}-{125\over 6})f'''(x)h^3+O(h^4)
$$
Now we want to set the cofficients of $f'(x)$ and of $f'''(x)$ because they are not given. So we need to calculate the linear equations system
$$
\\ a+b+c+d=0
\\a+3b-5b=0
\\0.5a+4.5b+12.5c=a
\\{a\over6}+{27b\over6}-{125c\over6}=0
$$

My question is why did they set the third equation they on $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They want to find a linear combinaison so that only the third order term remains. So they need to cancel the terms of other orders and have a non-zero number otherwise. They could have picked any non-zero value, it just turns out that it easier if you pick a.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Are you saying that the third equation could be $0.5a+4.5b+12.5c=1000a?$

Comment: I would have chosen $1$, to get $f''$ directly. Notice that if you set it to $1000a$ you get $f''(x)=\frac 1{1000 a}(af(x+h)+bf(x+3h)+cf(x-5h)+df(x))$.

Comment: Yes @mfl Exactly